# JS: How to assign an ID to a newly created HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Im building a dynamic form. The idea is that you can press a button to add new input fields, fill them up with string data and when you click submit it creates a div with this data in the correct format.

I got most of this working already, though the problem Im having is that only the first input field is being recognized, and any new text fields that have been created by JS are not.

The problem is that Im looking for the input's value by ID, but Im not sure what the ID of the newly created inputs is, thus Im unable to fetch it.

[I've setup a JSFiddle with my prototype](http://jsfiddle.net/bwrboq23/), but it's not working there even though it works correctly if I save the file and open it in a browser.

And here's the code just in case:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<style>
.HiddenDiv{
color: red;
}
</style>

<script>
//-----CREATES NEW INPUT LINE-----
var counter1 = 1;
var limit1 = 5;

function addInput(divName){
     if (counter1 == limit1)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter1 + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter1++;
     }
}
//-----TAKES VALUE AND PRINTS IT ON DIV-----
var counter2 = 0; //Prevents user from creating multiple nodes on submit
var limit2 = 1; //Amount of nodes that can be created per input field

function createNode(){
if (counter2 == limit2)  {
//Do nothing
}
else {
var input = document.getElementById('textInput1').value; //Retrieves input
var newText = document.createElement("li"); //Creates the HTML node
newText.innerHTML = input; //Sets the node's value to whatever is in the input

document.getElementById("Form").appendChild(newText); //Adds the node to the div

counter2++;
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="dynamicInput">
Job Requirements<br>
<input type="text" name="myInputs[]" id="textInput1">
</div>
<form method="POST">
<input type="button" value="+" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="return createNode()">
</form>

<div id="Form" class="HiddenDiv">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can set node id by using `node.setAttribute('id', 'your id')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be easier to use `document.querySelectorAll`:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="myInputs[]"');
```

and then you can obtain content from inputs in loop.